# Unpack function results into separate lists?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm optimizing my Python script and am interested if there's an opportunity to better structure a portion of my code. I run a function that returns 2 values, twice. I want the first returned values ie. result[0], and the second returned values i.e. result[1] in their own respective lists or tuples.

To be honest, I don't think it will be a huge performance increase either way, but now I'm curious.

This works, but I'm asking if I can do it better:

```
    out_1, result_1 = self.foo(data[0])
    out_2, result_2 = self.foo(data[1])

    results = (result_1, result_2)

    if results == (True, True):
        return (out_1, out_2), False

    elif results == (False, False) and out_1 == out_2:
        return out_1, True
```

Essentially, is there a way I can skip the assignment to variables, and immediately unpack the results into a tuple or list so I don't need to construct (result_1, result_2) and (out_1, out_2)?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to unpack the results from separate function calls?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim affirmative

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically this could be done, but it's actually going to be one line longer than what you already have. However you could modify the current code to remove the results variable.

For now I will assume you only will be calling self.foo the 2 times. That means the top should stay how it is.

```
out_1, result_1 = self.foo(data[0])
out_2, result_2 = self.foo(data[1])
```

Remove the results variable. But now modify the if statements to reflect that.

```
if all(r == True for r in [result_1, result_2]:
    return (out_1, out_2), False

elif all(r == False for r in [result_1, result_2] and out_1 == out_2:
    return out_1, True
```

This gives us a version where we did not have to make a new variable just to aggregate the date. However, since we are to assume there are only two result variables, we can still optimize this code further. The if statements, now have a loop that we don't strictly need for this check.

```
if True == result_1 == result_2:
    return (out_1, out_2), False

elif (False == result_1 == result_2) and out_1 == out_2:
    return out_1, True
```

Now the result variables are both directly compared to the boolean values in one step.